# How to find a window and push the button procedurally in WinAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to get the disk formatting dialog window handle and then press the button from my program. In other words, I have to open the disk formatting dialog manually:

[image]

And then I launch my program. The program is needed to find the dialog window (maybe using something such as  [FindWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, then find the "Start" button and [send a message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as it just pressed. How can I do this? I feel stuck.

Comment: There are Windows API functions to format drives.

Comment: I know, but I need to do it exactly the way I described.

Comment: And what if the format dialog changes in the next version of Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't.

For programmatic tasks, you use the programmatic APIs. Why would your program use the UI and simulate user input?

Eg. use the [Format method of Win32_Volume class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: No means no. Thanks a lot.